# ListBoxItem selection color disabled, but content is too

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

In relation to a previous question, I have the following code which disables the blue background:

```
<ListBox Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Transparent">
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Resources>
                <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
                <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Margin="5" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="LightGray" CornerRadius="5">
                <Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="#f7f7f7">
                    <!-- Content -->
                </Expander>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

What I'm noticing is that now all things like combo boxes that are in the content also have the same style of transparent selection.  What do I need to do to get the selection to only be transparent for the ListBoxItem and not for its contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set those brushes to their original value in the DataTemplate like so:

```
          <DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Blue" />
                    <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Blue" />
                </DataTemplate.Resources>
                <Border Margin="5" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="LightGray" CornerRadius="5">
                    <Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="#f7f7f7">
                        <!-- Content -->

                    </Expander>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works although I had to hardcode the 'standard' colors of #3399ff and #f0f0f0 respectively.  It would be nice to be able to get the original colors from the system.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to target `ListBoxItem` and add to the `ListBox` `Resources`

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <!-- Background of selected item when focussed -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
            <!-- Background of selected item when not focussed -->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
  </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Changing ListBox.Style to ListBox.Resources does eliminate the error but the behavior is the same as the original, a ComboBox or DataGrid inherits the transparent style.